# Error when running ElasticSearch as daemon in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, daemon

I get the following error while running elasticsearch as daemon in ubuntu:

```
daemon: fatal: failed to tell if ./elasticsearch is safe: No such file or directory
```

However, when I try to run the command manually it works:

```
./bin/elasticsearch -d -p pid
```

Please advise how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was my miss. Apparently, I installed an incorrect package, I installed from TAR. Whereas, I was supposed to install from DEB.

So, I followed [this document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/deb.html) from Elastic.

**Installing from the APT repository**

You may need to install the apt-transport-https package on Debian before proceeding:

`sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https`

Save the repository definition to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list:

`echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch`

But since I wanted a particular version 6.2.4, I used this:
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch=6.2.4`

**Running Elasticsearch with SysV initedit**
Use the update-rc.d command to configure Elasticsearch to start automatically when the system boots up:

`sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10`

Elasticsearch can be started and stopped using the service command:

`sudo -i service elasticsearch start`
`sudo -i service elasticsearch stop`

If Elasticsearch fails to start for any reason, it will print the reason for failure to STDOUT. Log files can be found in /var/log/elasticsearch/.